# JSF javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException and PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: jsf

I've search around a lot but can't see the problem. I've got something like this

```
<td><h:inputTextarea value="#{changecase.c.finalText}" cols="30" rows="10" /></td>
```

in my .xhtml file and my bean looks like this

```
@ManagedBean(name="changecase")
@RequestScoped
public class EditCase implements Serializable{
    private Case c;
    private int id;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.c = new Case(getId());
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.c = new Case(id);

    }

    public Case getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(Case c) {
        this.c = new Case(getId());
    }

    public String saveCase(Case c){

        return "success";
    }

    public EditCase(){

    }
```

Alright to the problem. If I remove my postconstruct I'll get a null pointer (PropertyNotFound) but I can see all the data in the textfields that it collects. And if I add the postconstruct I get no data, but an other exception. I saw that this has to do with the fact that in my .xhtml file, I've a value="", and that is looking for a set and not a get parameter, but I still want to print out the old data and from there make the change.

Is there anyone here that has a solution for this problem?

Comment: If you are submitting the page containing `<h:inputTextarea>`, then a broader scoped managed bean (at least a view scoped managed bean in this case) is necessary.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand you correctly, I should change the scope to a View, then add another bean that manage the data?